# Can I say that someone "got swayed"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, verbs

"Czech is disappointed with his mobile phone so easily got swayed by Pole to exchange his old model for brand-new American one" Does "got swayed" exist? I mean persuade.

Comment: I'd advise against this metaphoric use of *[to be] **swayed***. Better to stick with standard ***persuaded***.

Answer (score 1):

This might be OK in very informal speech but it would be better to write "was easily swayed".

Also, your use of "Czech" and "Pole" is not right. You would have to say "A Czech" and "A Pole" and more prescriptive grammarians might insist on "A Czech person" and "A Polish person".

Answer (score 0):

"Swayed" is fine here, but there are other problems with the sentence.

By "Czech" and "Pole" you seem to be referring to individuals, that is, to one person who is from the Czech Republic and another person who is from Poland. If so, you should say "a Czech/a Pole" if you had not previously introduced them or didn't know which Czech and Pole, or "the Czech/the Pole" if you were referring to specific people. That said, in English we rarely refer to individuals by their nationality like that. One would be more likely to use their names, or even a physical description, like "the old man" and "the tall girl". The only time English-speakers commonly refer to people by nationality is when it's clearly relevant. Like if you were talking about an international conference, you might say, "The Czech representative introduced a motion to reduce tariffs on sugar, while the Pole said that this was only acceptable if it was balanced by ..." etc.

Rather than "got swayed" you should say "is swayed" or "was swayed". Use of "got" as a helping verb is very informal.

And the sentence is a bit of a run on. You should have a conjunction, like "and", after "phone", or break it into two sentences.

Finally, normally in English narrative is given in the past tense, not the present.

Thus:

> The Czech was disappointed with his mobile phone and so was easily swayed by the Pole to exchange his old model for a brand-new American one.

Or more likely:

> Pavel was disappointed with his mobile phone and so was easily swayed by Stanislaw to exchange his old model for a brand-new American one.